# JQuery need to click twice to launch script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a show/hide div script that also logs the information when the user clicks to show the div. The logs work fine and the divs show/hide but only on second click, it did not use to do this before I added the log function.
I am a complete JS/JQuery noob so please explain where I've gone wrong!

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
function showAnswer(whichLayer,id,lang){
  var whichLayer, id, lang;
  if(document.getElementById(whichLayer).style.display =="none"){ 
     document.getElementById(whichLayer).style.display = "block";
  $.post("../../logclick.php", {id: id, lang: lang}); 
  }else{
     document.getElementById(whichLayer).style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>
```

Edit: code that calls the function.

```
<div class="question">
    <a href="javascript:showAnswer('2111692','1692','en')">Click here</a>
</div>
<div id="2111692" class="answer">Answer shows here.</div>
```

Stylesheet:

```
 .answer {
 clear: both;
 margin-left: 30px;
 display: none;
 }
```

Comment: How is this event hooked up?

Comment: Edited post to add call to function.

Comment: Are you sure your `style.display` is really `none`?

Comment: Why including jQuery and then using intrusive js / `document.getElementById` / `style.display`?

Comment: does onclick="showAnswer('<?=$theme_id.$link['id_lien']?>','<?=$link['id_lien']?>','<?=$lang?>')" work at all?

Comment: When discussing a client-side problem, please show client-side code as well (and not some PHP code, where no one here can tell what the outcome will be).

Comment: @putvande: Most likely it is _not_ … since CSS values can only be queried using the `style` object when they where set inline or previously whit the `style` object.

Comment: Well, that makes it the two click thing ;-)

Comment: So does that mean I have to move it from external CSS to inline?

Comment: @AndyHolmes thanks for the suggestion but it still only works on 2nd click.

Comment: @moonwave99 Because I already had the JS script and only modified it to add the $.post, as advised by fellow SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using (and tagging) jQuery, you could us `.is(':hidden')` to replace the `style.display == 'none'`:

```
function showAnswer(whichLayer, id, lang) {
    if ($('#' + whichLayer).is(':hidden')) {
        $('#' + whichLayer).show();
        $.post("../../logclick.php", {
            id: id,
            lang: lang
        });
    } else {
        $('#' + whichLayer).hide();
    }
}
```

You needed to click twice because the first time `style.display == 'none'` evaluates as `false`, therefore going into your `else` and setting the `style.display` actually to `none`.